# how to convert UITextField to Float in swift

Tags: swift, xcode

I am trying to convert some data types and cannot find anything helpful online. Data types in question are UITextField to Float - I tried doing it this way, but it does not work.

`let billTotalFormated = Float(billTotal.text ?? 0.0)`

the error I am getting is: Cannot convert value of type 'Double' to expected argument type 'String'.

I can force unwrap the value with the line:
`let billTotalFormated = Float(billTotal.text!)`, but heard that is not safe to do since it could throw errors.

Answer (score 1):

The closing parenthesis is at the wrong place

```
let billTotalFormated = Float(billTotal.text!) ?? 0.0
```

Force unwrapping the `text` property of an `UITextField` is *allowed* but you have to check if the string can be converted to `Float`

Comment: It's allowed, but may crash, depending on when it's called and whether billTotal.text is nil. My proposal is `Float(billTotal.text ?? "") ?? 0.0`, which at least produces a valid Float every time.

Comment: @a_hausb No, it doesn’t crash. The `text` property of `UITextField` (unlike `UILabel`) is never `nil` although it’s an optional.

Answer (score 0):

The force unwrap you're doing in `Float(billTotal.text!)` is to check if the `billTotal` text field contains any text. You can first check if `billTotal` contains text, and after that it's safe to unwrap it.

The purpose of the nil coalescing operator you're doing in `let billTotalFormated = Float(billTotal.text ?? 0.0)` would be to replace any invalid string in the text field with `0.0`.

```
if billTotal.text.isEmpty == false {
    // The text field contains something. Now try and get the value from it.
    billTotalFormated = Float(billTotal.text!) ?? 0.0
else {
    // Tell the user that the text field has an invalid value.
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you keep the float variable defined. Then check if the value in text field is not empty. You can do the following.

```
var float: Float = 0.0

if let text = billTotal.text {
  float = Float(text) ?? 0.0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are converting from String to float so:

```
let billTotalFormated = Float(billTotal.text ?? "")
```

as textfield returns optional String so use this syntax